# Can we show values from two different timelines in one worksheet in Tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

My problem statement is described below :
I have a calculated field, say Opportunity. There is pre defined rule from organization, that the target value for current month will be 1/3rd of the value of 2 months back. For example, The target opportunity value for April will be 1/3rd value of February. I need to show the current month's opportunity and the targeted value in the same worksheet. How to achieve this is Tableau?

I am getting the base data from tables in Oracle through a custom sql query, and calculating the opportunity value in Tableau for each row, and then showing the sum for a range of time , say last 6 months.

Comment: What is the distinction between 'Opportunity' and 'targeted value'?

Comment: Its the same, just that opportunity is a calculated field, and target opportunity is the 1/3rd of (current month-2) value

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to write the target value in SQL. It'll be easier (no need for data blending / complex calcs) and also more performant as it would be a hardcoded value in your dataset.

Comment: Yes thought so.. But the issue is there are some parameters in the calculation, which we have provided option to the user to change. Thats why the calculation is being done in Tableau and not the sql.

Comment: You might want to spell it all out in your question

Comment: which parts of the calculation are parameters?